# How to prove that two groups with different presentations are isomorphic in a naive way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

One can define a presentation of a group naively (ala Dummit-Foote in Chapter 1.2), i.e., as a group generated by certain elements with certain relations such that all other relations follow from the given ones. (By "naively" I mean not formally (as being an appropriate quotient of the free group on some letters).) I was wondering, what exactly does one need to show in order to prove that two "naively presented groups" (with different presentations) are isomorphic?

Comment: That's a *very* hard problem and there is ([and there can be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism_problem)) no formal algorithm to do that in general, let alone a user-friendly one.

Comment: In general, it is an almost hopeless problem. In some particular cases, it can be a rather challenging problem

Comment: @ArnaudMortier What if one of the presentations is very simple? For example, the trivial group, or a cyclic group? I mean, given the formal definition, to prove that there is an isomomrphism, one has to construct one between two quotients of free groups. But in the case of naive definition, I don't even understand properly what it means to be isomorphic, e.g. in the simple cases above. Say,  if one group is cyclic of order $n$, and the other has three generators and if I prove that the generators are equal and have order $n$, will it follow that the groups are isomorphic? How to justify it?

Comment: The trivial group can have impressively complex presentations...and ti can be very, very tough to prove the group is the trivial one.

Comment: @DonAntonio I see, but my question is more what does it formally mean to be isomorphic when we only have the naive definition of presentation rather than how to prove the existence of an isomorphism (in the latter case it's assumed that the notion of isomorphism is understood).

Comment: @user437309 If I'm interprating what you mean correctly, it would mean to show that the relations are basically the same on a basically same set of generators. If we restrict ourselves to finite sets of generators and relations, it could, in principle, be possible to prove the minimal set of (irredundant) generators in both groups has the same cardinality and the relations in one imply the relations in the other, and the other way around

Comment: You use Tietze transformations. It can be proved that if the groups are isomorphic then it can be proved in this way.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm aware of Tietze transformations, but the statement you mentioned can be proved (I believe) given the formal definition of group presentations (but not in the "naive context").

Comment: But they are intuitively clear, and you can still use them to prove two presentations isomorphic.